# Pixel width using glPointSize - no effect

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, opengl

I have this code for dropping points. I want to increase the point size. Right now I use this command `glPointSize` but nothing happens. The point size is default. It does not increase.
How can I increase my point size?

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);

glColor3f (a, b, c);
glPointSize(20.0f); 

glVertex2i(px, py);
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 15):

`glPointSize(20.0f);` has to be put before  `glBegin()`, otherwise it won't have any effect. Do it like this:

```
glPointSize(20.0f); 

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
   glColor3f (a, b, c);
   glVertex2i(px, py);
glEnd();
```

In OpenGL [documentation](http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glBegin.html), you can read that:

> Only a subset of GL commands can be used between glBegin and glEnd.
>   The commands are glVertex, glColor, glIndex, glNormal, glTexCoord,
>   glEvalCoord, glEvalPoint, glArrayElement, glMaterial, and glEdgeFlag.
>   Also, it is acceptable to use glCallList or glCallLists to execute
>   display lists that include only the preceding commands. If any other
>   GL command is executed between glBegin and glEnd, the error flag is
>   set and the command is ignored.